# Tracing source of this error: Call to a member function reorder() on boolean

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

Is there a way to trace this error:

> Call to a member function reorder() on boolean

[image]

I'm checking my PHP Logs but this particular error isn't showing up there.

It happens when I'm trying to create an article and make it featured, this error will show up. But if I refresh the list of articles, the article will have been created, and it is set as featured. So it looks like nothing went wrong, but I'm not sure if it's causing an issue somewhere else

Comment: if you turn on maximum errors AND debug it'll give you a stacktrace which will give you the filename and line number or at least it should - it's up to the template's error.php template to show it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of Helix have problems with Joomla 3.8.12+ - try updating to the latest Helix template. See [here](https://www.joomshaper.com/forums/helix-update).